# How do I grow tall Glowing Mushrooms?

Tags: terraria

I've planted a Glowing Mushroom farm before and got it to grow small Glowing Mushrooms. On the previous world I had created I actually got the tall Glowing Mushrooms to grown in the farm -- they looked very cool. I started a new world the other day on the 1.1 patch and I've noticed that -- even though I did the same things -- there were no large mushrooms. I suspect the depth is wrong, even though glowing mushrooms are growing.

Here are the things that I think you need to do:

- mud
- heat source (this seemed to help the tall Glowing Mushrooms on the last world, they were more likely to grow near a torch)
- depth (think anything under level is fine, but does the depth matter for tall Glowing Mushrooms?)
- time (wait, wait, wait)
- height (I think at least 20 blocks of space)

Comment: From what I recall lights actually make it harder to grow mushrooms. and for tall ones to grow their 'height' had to be below depth still.. Again not sure if this has changed since 1.1. I do not farm mushrooms any more (the caves are huge and run through them gets me more than enough)

Comment: I tested the lights theory on the last world. And note I didn't say lights I said heat source. Anyway on the last world, I planted mushroom grass seeds above a torch and away from a torch. The seeds above the torches grew tall mushrooms long before the ones away from the torches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set up two mushroom gardens to test this:

One: -200 feet, torches every few steps under the one block of mud, about 4 mushroom grass planted at the same time.

Two: -800 feet two mushroom grass planted at the same time, one with a torch underneath, one with no torch.

Result: In garden one the tall mushrooms grew all over the place at about the same time. In garden two the tall mushroom grew under the torchless portion first.

Conclusion: torches don't really matter, just be at negative depth, give about 20-25 blocks of space above. Above all, wait. The tall mushrooms take a while to show up.

Comment: @BBz yeah I forgot... no points for answering your own question tho

Comment: I have attempted this same experiment, with, also, inconclusive results. I really don't think it matters what depth or heat is used.